# how to Add multiple component in parent component with Angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular6

In **parent.component.html**

I have the following HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary (click)="AddComponentAdd()">Address</button> 
<app-addresse *ngFor="let addres of collOfAdd" [add]="addres"></app-addresse>
```

and in **parent.component.ts**

```
private collOfAdd: Array<AddresseComponent> = [];

AddComponentAdd() {
    this.collOfAdd.push(AddresseComponent); 
}
```

and in **addresse.component.ts**

```
 @Input() add: string;
```

How do I make the component `<app-addresse>` appear several times in the parent component by clicking the button present in parent component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a stackblitz for your question please check the below url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tihubf

In this reference you can find hello.component loaded multiple times on click of button.

Answer (score 1):

I also created a stackblitz link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnyec5

Comment: @Fat16 I didn't get how the above stackblitz code worked for you? there is no button in the answer provided?

Comment: I made changes to your solution !